# echo in console connection

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial, cisco

I use pyserial in python to connect to cisco console port:

```
>>> import serial
>>> console = serial.Serial('COM5')
>>> console.read(console.inWaiting())
''
>>> console.write('sh ip inter brie\n')
17L
>>> console.read(console.inWaiting())
'sh ip inter brie\r\nInterface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Statu
s                Protocol\r\nFastEthernet0              unassigned      YES NVRA
M  up                    down    \r\nFastEthernet1              unassigned
YES manual up                    down    \r\nBRI0                       unassign
ed      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    \r\nBRI0:1
unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    \r\nBRI0:2
        unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    \r\nFastEtherne
t2              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down    \r\nFas
tEthernet3              unassigned      YES unset  up                    down
 \r\nFastEthernet4              unassigned      YES unset  up
 down    \r\nFastEthernet5              unassigned      YES unset  up
         down    \r\nFastEthernet6              unassigned      YES unset  up
                 down    \r\nFastEthernet7              unassigned      YES unse
t  up                    down    \r\n --More-- '
>>>
```

It works good except there is echo in reply. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"there is echo in reply"*? All I can see there is the response to your command.

Comment: i send command 'sh ip inter brie\n' and responce starts with 'sh ip inter brie\r\n'. There is no reason to send the command back to me. I know it is possible to switch off echo in telnet and i with to know if it is possible in console connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that cisco is buggy with serial echo switch off. The function doesn't work. Putty manage incoming text row and modify it to make it look as we want to see

Thus there are two possible solution:

1. Manage incoming text row as putty does
2. Use putty-like apps if it is possible